# Are there any known standards or security flaws in password-protected ZIP files?

Tags: security, zip, passwords

Just like the title says.  I was hoping someone could direct me to documents/resources that show how to encrypt a zip file such that most (if not all) 3rd-party apps can open it.

I'm more interested in the security aspect rather than how to do it - any knowledge is welcome.

This is to casually protect files on my work computer (and network drive) from prying co-workers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There aren't any big flaws in ZIPs password.  There are tools that can crack a zip file password but they have to do it using brute force, usually starting with a dictionary attack.   For protecting files locally or on a network, it should be fine as long as you pick a long enough password.  I'd suggest using a phrase like 'givemelibertyorgivemedeath' or whatever. Long enough to make brute force attacks unfeasible but short enough to keep from being a pain to type everything you need to unlock a file.

Comment: I'll try not to use that one, considering some coworkers also use SO. :)

Answer (score 3):

[WinZip has defined](http://www.winzip.com/aes_info.htm) how to use AES encryption on zip entries.

It is a WinZip thing but many tools support WinZip's AES design, including InfoZip, WinRar (I think?), and DotNetZip.  WinZip's approach has also been granted FIPS-197 certification.

It is much stronger than the old-style PKZIP "Weak" encryption.